# certain applications looks tiny on high def screen

Tags: hdpi

On my Lenovo yoga laptop with Ubuntu 18, I installed notepad++. And it looks really tiny. I'm not sure why it only happens with this app. Is there a way to change settings for a single app only?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/16831/680651

Comment: its not just the font, the entire UI looks tiny

Comment: that app isn't following the HiDPi settings of the desktop; so you've either got to switch to another app, find a 'later' source (of that app), or find a way around it (like changing fonts) until the devs update it to use HiDPi settings of your DEsktop.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! 1) What's the display resolution and density? 2) How did you install Notepad++? 3) Can you please provide a screenshot? Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @guiverc There is a work-around for a single app but the duplicate question's answers didn't address how to solve this OP's question. As I can no longer post an answer here I posted the solution on the duplicate.